# Master Equation -> Fokker-Planck Equation

Tags: statistical-mechanics, probability, non-equilibrium, stochastic-processes

Suppose we have the master equation $$\partial_{t}P_{n}(t)=a(n+1)nP_{n+1}(t)+b(n-1)P_{n-1}(t)-[an(n-1)+bn]P_{n}(t)$$ where $a$ and $b$ are constants. I would like to take the continuum limit of this equation to obtain the Fokker-Planck form $$\partial_{t}P(n,t)=-\partial_{n} \{[bn-an(n-1)]P(n,t)\}+\frac{1}{2}\partial_{n}^2\{[bn+an(n-1)]P(n,t)\}$$ However for some reason I cannot get this to work. I have tried taylor expanding the master equation to second order using $$P_{n+1}(t)=P(n,t)+\partial_{n}P(n,t)+\frac{1}{2}\partial_{n}^{2}P(n,t)+...$$ $$P_{n-1}(t)=P(n,t)-\partial_{n}P(n,t)+\frac{1}{2}\partial_{n}^{2}P(n,t)+...$$ and collecting terms in each derivative of $P(n,t)$. Then I expand the derivatives in the second equation and collect terms of each kind. However they don't seem to match (the algebra is long so I won't bother posting it here). So is there something I am missing? Thanks for any help :)

Update: so I believe the above approach may be a little off. I think I should first set $$P_{n}(t)\rightarrow P(x,t)$$ $$n\rightarrow x$$ $$n+1\rightarrow  x+\Delta x$$ $$n-1 \rightarrow x-\Delta x$$ and then taylor expand in $\Delta x$. I should then keep terms only up to order $\Delta x^2$ and at the end set $\Delta x=1$ and $x=n$. This improves things a little, however the two results are still slightly different.

Comment: I am pretty sure this derivation is standard as I remember seeing it in my Complex Systems lectures. Did you try refering to any textbook?

Comment: @Sanya Yes, I can't find anything similar - do you have any recommendations?

Comment: My lecture was a bit ago, so I don't remember any literature. Quick googling yielded https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0701242.pdf and http://www.it.uu.se/research/publications/reports/2005-044/2005-044-nc.pdf which might be a good starting point, especially looking at their references.

Comment: @Sanya Thanks - I will have a look, although I have been through a lot of stuff already to no avail. I am mainly concerned that the FP form could be incorrect. Shouldn't a general FP equation have the form (in one dimension) $\partial_{t}P(x,t)=-\partial_{x}[v(x)P(x,t)]+\partial_{x}[D(x)\partial_{x}P(x,t)]$ - the positions of the derivatives in term two are a bit different to this...